# Discord.js timing out members

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm using node.js to make a discord bot for my server, I am currently trying to timeout someone on command, e.g. 'Me-bot.timeout'... Response-'Bot-Who would you like to timeout?' then you type there username and it times them out.
I thought this code would work but it doesn't, how do I fix it/what am I doing wrong?

```
message.guild.members.cache.get('username#1234').timeout(9000, 'Admin timed you out.')
```

Comment: The [timeout](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=timeout) function returns a Promise. Add a `.catch` to check if this promise is being rejected with an error.

Comment: @byxor, what would be the correct syntax, can you please write it out? :)

Comment: There's an example in the link

Comment: There must be some confusion, i know that there is an error, and i know that its not working, but what could i do to make it work? @byxor

Comment: The error parameter in your `catch` callback will tell you the reason of the error. Without this one can only guess

Comment: Please excuse me if I don't make sense, I am still new to discord bot development, you see, i launch the bot through cmd (command prompt), if there is an error, it will show inside of cmd. This is how I can debug certain features.

Comment: I understand. In the code you've shared, you call [timeout](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=timeout) function, but you don't use the return value of this function. This function returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You need to provide a handler function to the `.catch` method if you want to see any errors that occurred when the library attempted to fulfil this promise. E.g. `.timeout(9000, 'reason').catch(console.error);`. If there is no `catch` handler, the error is ignored.

Comment: yes, but the error isn't being ignored, it is being displayed in cmd. What i am asking for is a line of code that is possibly similar to what i previously had, and it times out a member.

Comment: The error from `timeout` is being ignored with 100% certainty if you're running the code you've shared. If you're receiving an error elsewhere, please include it in the question otherwise nobody will know what the problem is

Comment: the error i receive is this:
.timeout(9000, 'reason') is not a function
^

Comment: Are you fetching a user correctly for your version of `discord.js`? In version 12 onwards, you need to use `message.guild.members.fetch(id)` to get a promise for a user. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch

Comment: alright, so if i understand this correctly, why wouldn't this syntax work? 

message.guild.members.fetch('username#1234').timeout(9000, 'reason')

Comment: i tried that syntax but it gave me the error:
message.guild.members.fetch(...).timeout is not a function

Comment: `timeout` is not a function that exists on a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Explaining promises is outside the scope of this question. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as [byxor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5601284/byxor) mentioned, you should be using `message.guild.members.fetch` in Discord.js v12 and above.

That being said, `fetch` is going to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for a user, and not the user object itself. You need to handle this promise to get the resolved user before attempting to time them out.

This is all explained in the [Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch), but this is generally what you're looking for (with all possible errors caught if you need them):

```js
message.guild.members.fetch('id')
  .then(user => {
    user.timeout(9000, 'Admin timed you out.')
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Timed user out for 9000 seconds.')
    })
    .catch(console.error)
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```

I would highly recommend you read up on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), as Discord.js is going to utilize them heavily.